# How to use wordpress function wp_enqueue_script() in php?

Tags: php, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have a php function as shown below. The following function is being used at many places.

```
function render_brightcove_player($active_feed, $poster_image = false)
{
    $poster = '';
    if ($poster_image) {
        $poster = 'poster=' . esc_url($poster_image);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="hsc-video" onclick="hscLogo()">
        <div class="hsc-video__inner">
            <script src="//players.brightcove.net/1242843915001/SJ3Tc5kb_default/index.min.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    wp_enqueue_script(                                      
    'miscellaneous-scripts',
    HSC_TEMPLATE_URL . "/assets/js/miscellaneous.js"
    );
}
```

I have added wordpress function `wp_enqueue_script()`. Inside miscellaneous.js file I am using:

```
function hscLogo() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("hsc-tv-logo")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

I am wondering if that is the right way to use `wp_enqueue_script()` function in php. Do I need to place **wp_enqueue_script()** somewhere else ?

This is the first time I am using `wp_enqueue_script` in wordpress. Here is the tree structure of javascript folders/files.

[image]

Comment: Where is `render_brightcove_player` and when is it called? Is there a reason you don't enqueue it always then check in JS if the thing you want to hide is showing/exists? You're meant to enqueue scripts in a particular hook, doing it outside that hook _sometimes_ works but it depends on _when_ you do it rather than _how_ you do it

Comment: `render_brightcove_player` is called at many places. I am wondering if its not a good practice if I enqueue inside a php function ? Where we usually enqueue our scripts ?

Comment: that render function is called at many places and is used for live streaming applications.

Comment: The official doc has an example of how to use the function and the hook. Do you mean to say that `render_brightcove_player` is being used on the frontend in various templates, called directly? Or is it a shortcode? Or is it on a hook? In the header? Footer?

Comment: Yes it is being used on the frontend in various templates and called directly as well. Its not a shortcode, neither hook nor header/footer.

Comment: Note that it's unclear how the code is calling `hscLogo`, it may not get called, or it may be called before the logo is created. I would also note that if there is more than one element with the HTML class `hscLogo`, only the first will be hidden, the others will remain. If none are found that code will generate errors

Comment: There is a player inside that div. The player has play button. On clicking that play button, I want to hide a logo present in that particular player.

Comment: Is there way we can do through css only ?

Comment: There may be, but that's not what you asked, and CSS questions don't belong on here

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if that is the right way to use wp_enqueue_script() function in php. Do I need to place wp_enqueue_script() somewhere else ?

Not really, here's what the official docs say in the notes:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

> **The function should be called using the wp_enqueue_scripts action hook if you want to call it on the front-end of the site, like in the examples above.** To call it on the administration screens, use the admin_enqueue_scripts action hook. For the login screen, use the login_enqueue_scripts action hook. Calling it outside of an action hook can lead to problems, see the ticket #11526 for details.

The way you're doing it might work as it will try to print scripts out in the footer, assuming your theme is built correctly and makes all the right calls, e.g. `wp_head`, `wp_footer`, etc

But further than that, the approach is wrong.

Instead of:

- When Brightcove player HTML is printed

  - enqueue the script
  - Hide a logo using a `hscLogo` function in the script that's called by doing ????

The code should:

- Always enqueue the script
- on the DOM ready, check for a brightcove player

  - if a brightcove player is found, remove the logo

Or better yet, instead of using javascript, put this CSS in your stylesheet:

```css
.hsc-tv-logo {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS ? I want to hide a logo only on click of a play button.

Comment: If I add css, then it will disappear permanently.

Comment: Does your javascript not do the same thing? At this point we're talking about something else that isn't the question. The question was about how to enqueue javascript

Comment: The reason why I asked because you mentioned "Instead of using javascript, put this CSS in your stylesheet."

Comment: I would be very happy to know how we can do this only through CSS.

Comment: I literally put the CSS to do this in my answer, but as I said **that is not what you asked in your question**, CSS only questions are offtopic here too, this is not the place to ask